# Свойство для подключения к таблице БД в StringGrid

Tags: dbgrid, delphi, sql-server

Как превратить компонент StringGrid в DBStringGrid так, чтобы без проблем работало с MS SQL Server?

Известно, что `StringGrid` позволяет обращаться к значению каждой ячейки, используя 
`for i...do`, а компонент `DBGrid` не может. Вопрос: как в `StringGrid` добавить свойство для подключения к таблице БД MS SQL Server 2008? Очень надеюсь на вашу подсказку. Работаю в Delphi 7.

Объект `Table  TStringGrid`
Свойство `ColCount = 2`
Процедура при нажатии кнопки "Расчет" на форме примерно такая:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i, j, neis, rez : Integer;
    tmp : Currency;
begin
q := 0;

for i := 1 to Table.RowCount -1 do
  begin
  for j := 1 to Table.ColCount -1 do
    begin
    if Table.Cells[j, i] = '' then Table.Cells[j, i] := '0';
    Application.ProcessMessages;
       end;
  end;
for i := 1 to Table2.RowCount -1 do
  begin
  for j := 1 to Table2.ColCount -1 do
    begin
    if Table2.Cells[j, i] = '' then Table2.Cells[j, i] := '0';
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    sleep(10);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Почему вы не можете прогнать цикл по DBGrid?

Answer (score 1):

Вы что волшебник, чтобы что-то превращать?
Берете из `DataSet` данные, парсите их ручками и пишите в `StringGrid`. Но нужно ли Вам это?

А обращаться к данным в каждой ячейке можно через тот же `DataSet`.

**ДОБАВЛЕННО**

Весь сыр бор из за того что нужно заменить пустые ячейки на 0.
Печально, но неужели на этапе проектирования архитектуры базы, нельзя было этим полям назначить значение по умолчанию?
Да даже сейчас, ни кто вам не мешает сделать это.
В крайнем случае можно сделать запрос , чтобы перед выборкой на стороне сервера в таблицу записался 0 вместо пустого поля.
Нет предпочитаем извращаться над StringGrid ом, тем более циклом, проходи дважды по таблице, тоесть если записей тысяч 10 то тормозить это будет ужасно.

Answer (score 1):

`StringGrid` и `DBGrid` - компоненты представления данных. Для работы в DELPHI другие компоненты существуют, в которых после запроса и находятся полученные результаты и с ними можно работать там как с массивами) Вы бы лучше сказали, что вам в конечном итоге надо - возможно, все это решается с помощью стандартных компоненетов и изобретать велосипед не надо будет)

Comment: Хотелось бы отобразить таблицу БД с сервера в гриде, а затем обработать (рассчитать) по алгоритму, используя значения в её ячейках (for i ...do...). Причем алгоритм рассчета выполняется по нажатию на кнопке формы Delphi приложения.

Comment: Из сказаного вижу 2 пути:
1. ВОзможно алгоритм рассчета сделать на сервере БД - тоесть составить SQL запрос удовлетворяющий вашему алгоритму рассчета.
2. Если 1пункт невозможно - то работайте с компонентом DataSet как с двумерным массивом
как подключаетесь к БД -какой компонент используйте?

Comment: Да. Вы правы - на сервере обрабатывать лучше всего. Но вот загвоздка - я не знаю, как этот расчет перенести в SQL-запрос.

Comment: Таблицу в студию (поля) и что надо посчитать)

Comment: Объект Table `TStringGrid`<br>
Свойство `ColCount = 2`

Процедура при нажатии кнопки "Расчет" на форме примерно такая:

    procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var i, j, neis, rez : Integer;
        tmp : Currency;
        ini1, ini2 : TIniFile;
    begin
    q := 0;
    
    for i := 1 to Table.RowCount -1 do
      begin
      for j := 1 to Table.ColCount -1 do
        begin
        if Table.Cells[j, i] = '' then Table.Cells[j, i] := '0';
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        sleep(30);
        end;
      end;

Comment: ПРально я понял: если в 1-ом столбце пустое значение, то нада поставить 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто **отображать** нолики вместо пустоты, то как один из вариантов, определить обработчик OnDrawDataCell у DBGrid. И не надо выдумывать лишний геморрой с TStringGrid:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawDataCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if Field.IsNull then
    DBGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 5, Rect.Top, '0');
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Я попробую.